# Meteor.js embed iframe safely

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe, meteor, embed

I have a meteor.js app which contains a chat. We need to allow users post embed code from youtube and soundcloud. Safely.

I use djedi:sanitize-html-client to sanitize user inputs other than the ones containing "youtube" and "soundcloud.com"

So, for YouTube, I got it working where I take that user input string, for example

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B65pLsah3XE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

, then split it on space, and loop through the array to find a valid url using this RegEx:

```js
var pattern = new RegExp("(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?");
```

After that, if a valid url was found, I reconstruct iframe html in code, insert into Mongo per usual, and it's displayed in the chat window. This part is working.

But this approach does not work for soundcloud embed code, example:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/227010461&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

RegEx does not find the match in that soundcloud iframe code.

So, my question is: How do I either RegEx these two urls from soundcloud embed html, or is there a safe way in Meteor.js to allow embeding iframe.

Comment: Your regex [works...](https://regex101.com/r/iT0pA3/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use this JS code :

```
var getHostname = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l.hostname;
};
```

And use it within your code:

```
getHostname("https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/227010461&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true")
```

which returns:

> "w.soundcloud.com"

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get both URLs, because I need the track ID.

Comment: @FloridaGard I'm sorry, I don't catch what your mean